# Make a package from xproj

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

I create web application in visual studio 2015 with .NET 4.6.

Now I want to make a package from this project.

Is it possible to make a package tools or maybe some special configuration in project.json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is [dnu publish](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility#publish-dnu-publish). You can use it to package any DNX application to a NuGet package. For projects that define startup commands (such as `dnx web`) it also creates scripts to invoke those commands.

The base syntax is:

```
dnu publish -o outputpath
```

If you want to include the DNX runtime, you can append `--runtime <runtimeversion>`, and if you want the package to be binary-only, you can specify `--no-source`.